# View full transaction information in Google Analytics

Tags: magento, google-analytics, e-commerce

We have an e-commerce store based on Magento 1.
Google Analytics is configured in Magento and e-commerce tracking is activated in GA.
I would like to see full information for concrete order (transaction): full referrer or search query, information about the customer (country, browser and how much time he spent on the site).

I'm trying to find this information in `Conversions -> Ecommerce -> Transactions`. When I add Secondary dimension filter "Full Referrer", it shows me "paypal.com/webapps/hermes" (because order was placed using PayPal), however I would like to know the exact referrer site.

How can I see this information?

Comment: You need to add paypal.com to the referral exclusion list in the property settings. This will apply only to future transactions, the data for existing transactions is lost as changing the campaign information (in this case setting a new referrer by visiting a payment gateway) will start a new session (so might also affect conversion rates). This is a configuration issue rather than a code issue and might be off-topic for stackoverflow.

Comment: @EikePierstorff thanks! added to the exclusion list, will see how it goes.